# Find where a timestamp vector changes timezones

Tags: r, timezone

How can I find the element in a timestamp vector where it switches to a different time zone due to the time changeover?

Sample data:

```
ts <- structure(c(1521921600, 1521925200, 1521928800, 1521932400, 1521936000, 
                              1521939600, 1521943200, 1521946800, 1521950400, 1521954000, 1521957600
            ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
```

---

Output:

```
"2018-03-24 21:00:00 CET"  "2018-03-24 22:00:00 CET"  "2018-03-24 23:00:00 CET"  "2018-03-25 00:00:00 CET"  "2018-03-25 01:00:00 CET"  "2018-03-25 03:00:00 CEST" "2018-03-25 04:00:00 CEST" "2018-03-25 05:00:00 CEST" "2018-03-25 06:00:00 CEST" "2018-03-25 07:00:00 CEST" "2018-03-25 08:00:00 CEST"
```

The first 5 elements are in **CET** and then it switches to **CEST**. So the answer here would be 5 or 6. Both answers would be fine.

In the sample data the difference is always 1 hour, but I need it aswell for different time intervalls, for example 15 or 30 minutes.

```
seq(min(ts), to = max(ts), by = 15*60)
seq(min(ts), to = max(ts), by = 30*60)
```

The expected answer for 15 min would be 20/21.
The expected answer for 30 min would be 10/11.

Comment: You can ues `dst(ts)` from `lubridate`. That will give you TRUE/FALSE for whether you're in daylights saving time or not.

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for. I didnt know about that function. If you write it as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lubridate`'s `dst`:

```
which(!duplicated(dst(ts)))[2]
```

This will give you the point where the time zone changes to DST.

Comment: right! Forgot that it's TRUE/FALSE already. Mind you, this is only when you're switching from non-DST to DST. My solution will also catch the other way around.